# Why is the tee command necessary?

Tags: command-line, tee

On Ubuntu my Brightness keys don't work.
So instead to open Ubuntu settings every time, I want to write a shell script to use in my .bashrc.
Now I don't understand at all why the tee command in the following line seems to be neessary! Thanks!

```
sudo echo "937" | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Comment: because redirection will not work with sudo... there are other ways of doing it, but tee is nice

Comment: So you understand what this command does and just don't know why `tee` is used or what? You can skip the first `sudo` )) and it will do same.

Comment: @Zanna Why redirection does not work with sudo?

Comment: @Zanna Your comment is partly wrong. Even in root shell this does not work:                      root@mycomputer:   echo "200" |  /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness                                      bash: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness: Permission denied

Comment: @Zanna What other ways of doing it are there?

Comment: The thing that's really not necessary about this command is the `sudo` before `echo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tee` is not necessary in that command.

You just need to edit the file `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` to add `937`, as the file is only writeable by the owner, `root` (user with UID 0), any manner that can do exactly that would suffice.

You could just do:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "937" >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness'
```

In that command, `tee` is being run with `sudo` i.e. being run as `root` as the file `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` in only writable by `root`.

Even you can start an interactive-login session of your `SHELL` for `root` by:

```
sudo -i
```

and open-write-close the file with any command or your editor of choice (and later exit that session), but that would be clumsy and unnecessary as you want to run just a single command.

Also you don't need the `sudo` with `echo`, do:

```
echo "937" | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Comment: So why is    sudo bash -c 'echo "937" >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness'  possible but the same command in a root shell does not work

Comment: `sudo` will make you `root` (default), when in a `root` shell just do: `echo "937" >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Comment: The idea is that this won't work: `sudo something > some_file` -- the redirection occurs as **you**, not root.

Comment: @glennjackman But in a `root`'s shell, that's moot.

Comment: Of course, but working in a root shell is like running with scissors.